# MySQL - get youngest entry with group by / order by

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table like this:

```
| id    | created_at          | subscriptionId | orderId |
|-------|---------------------|----------------|---------|
| 32247 | 2021-12-13 16:49:21 |           6773 |  600724 |
| 32246 | 2021-12-13 16:26:02 |           6773 |  600717 |
| 32245 | 2021-12-13 16:23:53 |           6773 |  600715 |
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT
st.subscriptionId,
st.orderId,
st.created_at
FROM subscription_time st
WHERE
st.subscriptionId IN (6773)
GROUP BY st.subscriptionId
ORDER BY st.created_at DESC;
```

I get this result:

```
| subscriptionId | orderId | created_at          |
|----------------|---------|---------------------|
|           6773 |  600715 | 2021-12-13 16:23:53 |
```

I would suspect the entry with the `id=32247` and not the one with `id= 32245` ? Do I have to run it with a subquery?

Comment: group by doesnt have st.orderId, st.created_at in your query. its interesting it works with no error .  What is your desired output ?

Comment: You can use: ** MIN(st.orderId),** in the SELECT to get the lowest irderNumber